# Is it possible to append a string to an Android activity titlebar?

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to append a string to an Android activity titlebar without needing to rebuild it entirely?

Comment: `setTitle(getTitle()+" thing to append")` would seem like a likely candidate. What do you mean by "rebuild it entirely"?

Comment: Ah, I was thinking I might need to redefine the title view in XML. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Activity.setTitle ()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setTitle%28java.lang.CharSequence%29)